# Python error list index is out of range

Tags: python, indexing

I know this is a rookie question but I keep getting an error I don't usually get.
"Index error: List index out of range on line 12." where it says the 2 'nums'. I thought it was perfectly fine to call variables out side of a loop?

```
lisp = []
new = []

for x in range(1, 11):
    num = int((x * (3*x - 1))/2)
    lisp.append(num)

x = 0
y = 2

for i in lisp[1:]:
    num1 = lisp[x] + i
    num2 = lisp[y] + i
    dif1 = i - lisp[x]
    dif2 = lisp[y] - i
    smallList = [num1, num2, dif1, dif2]
    new.append(smallList)

    x += 1
    y += 1

print(new)
```

Comment: Have you tried doing some debugging - add some print statements immediately before the line you are getting the error, to print the list, and the index you are using into it.

Comment: I'm and egg, I forgot by the time it gets to the 10th element the list index will be out of range.

Answer (score 2):

Fix using `ipython`.

**script.py**:

```
lisp = []
new = []

for x in range(1, 11):
    num = int((x * (3*x - 1))/2)
    lisp.append(num)

x = 0
y = 2

for i in lisp[1:]:
    num1 = lisp[x] + i
    num2 = lisp[y] + i
    dif1 = i - lisp[x]
    dif2 = lisp[y] - i
    smallList = [num1, num2, dif1, dif2]
    new.append(smallList)

    x += 1
    y += 1

print(new)
```

Launch `ipython` and do:

```
In [1]: run script.py
     11 for i in lisp[1:]:
     12     num1 = lisp[x] + i
---> 13     num2 = lisp[y] + i
     14     dif1 = i - lisp[x]
     15     dif2 = lisp[y] - i

IndexError: list index out of range

In [2]: y
Out[2]: 10

In [3]: len(lisp)
Out[3]: 10
```

Here `y = 10`, but `len(lisp) = 10` valid index are between `0` and `9` (both inclusive, 0-based) and 10 is out of this range.

Answer (score 0):

Check and put conditions on:

```
x += 1
y += 1
```

`y` is going beyond the index on the line:

```
num2 = lisp[y] + i
```